# How to add description for MBean method to see it in jmx-console of JBOSS

Tags: java, jboss, jmx

I'm using JBoss 4.3.2.GA

I've added method to my MBean service. Method has several arguments in signature. It works fine but I want more.

Problem: when I see method signature in jmx-console, I don't know what every of this input fields means, because jmx-console doesn't show arguments names, only input fields for values.

Is there ability add description of every argument (in Java code, not xml) allowing to show this description in jmx-console of JBOSS?

I've tried to use Spring annotation: `@ManagedOperation` to add at least method description but no results (description is not showed in jmx-console).

May be some one have resolved such issue...

Comment: Spring's `@ManagedOperation` works just fine for this. How are you configuring it?

Comment: If you Spring annotation, you need to have a Spring container in which you objects gets instantiated. And you need to switch on scanning for those annotations on your Spring Beans with <context:mbean-export/>

Answer (score 3):

In Java, you can do this, if you don't use standard MBeans, but e.g. `DynamicMBean`s for which you need to implement `getMBeanInfo()` which is returning all that data.
This is a generic way, not limited to JBoss. But it is also a lot of work, which (IMO) only makes sense if you really need the dynamic features of a DynamicMBean.

For completeness sake (and as this may be the easier approach):

You can write an xmbean-descriptor and put that e.g. into $SERVER/conf/xmdesc/
In addition to this you need to enhance the standard MBeean-descriptor like this (note the `xmbean-dd` attribute:

```
<mbean code="org.jnp.server.NamingBeanImpl"
   name="jboss:service=NamingBeanImpl"
   xmbean-dd="resource:xmdesc/NamingBean-xmbean.xml">
</mbean>
```

This example is taken from $SERVER/conf/jboss-service.xml and the NamingBean-xmban.xml is in the path described by the attribute.

Comment: Where do you deploy the type definition of the custom MBean ? Within a sar ?

Comment: If you mean the xmbean-descriptor shown above, then this goes as flat file somewhere in the classpath - standard for system delivered ones is server/default/conf/xmdesc/, which is the same as resource:xmdesc

Comment: Sorry, I meant the (custom) classes which are referenced within the descriptors. If I'm not totally wrong, they need to be somehow on the classpath, and if one don't want to mess with the global JBoss classpath, the class definitions needs to be somehow deployed (within the deploy/ directory)

Comment: Ah, the mbean itself and its classes? You have two options there: 1) packages everything in a sar  2) have the classes e.g. in a jar in server/default/lib/ and then reference them in a -service.xml file

Answer (score 3):

I have created a small [wrapper](http://udojava.com/2012/11/13/adding-descriptions-to-jmx-beans-using-an-annotation-wrapper/) that will create a dynamic MBean out of a normal Java class through annotations. With it you can also add descriptions to beans, attributes, operations and parameters.

***It also supports externalization and localization of names and descriptions using Java ResourceBundles.***

Example of an annotated class:

```
@JMXBean(description = "My first JMX bean test")
public class MyBean {
    int level = 0;

    @JMXBeanAttribute(name = "Floor Level", description = "The current floor level")
    public int getLevel() {
      return level;
    }

    @JMXBeanAttribute
    public void setLevel(int newLevel) {
      level = newLevel;
    }

    @JMXBeanOperation(name = "Echo Test", description = "Echoes the parameter back to you")
    public String myMethod(
             @JMXBeanParameter(name = "Input", description = "String of what to echo") String param) {
      return "You said " + param;
    }
}
```

Example of an annotated class using ResourceBundles:

```
@JMXBean(resourceBundleName="com.example.my.package.BundleName")
public class MyBean {

  int level = 0;

  @JMXBeanAttribute(nameKey="level", descriptionKey="levelDescription")
  public int getLevel() {
    return level;
  }
}
```

How to use it:

```
MyBean bean = new MyBean();
JMXBeanWrapper wrappedBean = new JMXBeanWrapper(bean);
MBeanServer mbs = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
mbs.registerMBean(wrappedBean, new Objectname("com.example.my.package:type=TestBean,name=My Bean"));
```

You can find the source on [GitHub](https://github.com/uklimaschewski/JMXWrapper)

Comment: Please do not duplicate your answers. If the question has a duplicate then flag the question is a duplicate; if not, then please tailor your answer to the question asked.

Answer (score 1):

I've had success with mixing Spring XML and Spring annotations where I had multiple MBeans of the same Java class. The approach allowed tight control over bean names and allowed me to define descriptions etc at the class level. I needed to define an annotation based bean assembler for an MBeanExporter, and supply a map of bean names and bean references:

```
<bean id="exporter" class="org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter"
      lazy-init="false">
    <property name="server" ref="mbeanServer" />
    <property name="assembler">
        <!-- will create management interface using annotation metadata -->
        <bean class="org.springframework.jmx.export.assembler.MetadataMBeanInfoAssembler">
            <property name="attributeSource">
                <bean class="org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.AnnotationJmxAttributeSource"/>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="beans">
        <map>
           <!-- entries -->
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

An example of what I read from Java annotations might be:

```
@ManagedAttribute(description = "A detailed description to show in JConsole tooltips etc")
public String getFoo() {
    return foo;
}
```

I had the assemblers defined privately to the exporter, but you could share those beans more widely I'm sure.

BTW this was on Tomcat.